# How to start rabbit mq on starting node server

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am currently extending out nodejs back end servcies to use RabbitMQ. I am trying to use AMQP library to use rabbitmq with node.js. I did observe to start the RabbitMQ most of them are writing the code in index/send/receive/app.js and starting the message broker with a command node app.js/send.js/receive.js/index.js. I have my nodejs folder structure like this

```
 /Application NodeJS
        /node_modules
        /public
           /module1
           /module2
           /module3
           /app.js
           /logger.js
        /test
        manifest.yml
        package.json
        build.sh
        deploy.sh
```

In this scenario if I would like to add my rabbit.js file where can i add that and how do I start my broker on server startup ?

Can somebody help me with this please.

Thanks!

Comment: Just create a context (https://github.com/squaremo/rabbit.js/blob/master/example/easyamqp/server.js) then set stuff up on the ready event. Not sure what you mean by where rabbit.js should go (just a dependency in package.json)?

Comment: @MatthewCampbell Rabbit.js in this context is the file containing all the code related to my rabbitmq broker. Start the connection, publisher etc.